# Problem with DSolve in Mathematica to solve PDEs

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I was using DSolve in Mathematica to solve PDEs as follows:

```
DSolve[{4*(-5 + 8*v)*Ur[r] + 6*(-3 + 4*v)*U\[Phi][r] == 2*r*(4*(-1 + v)*Derivative[1][Ur][r] + 3*Derivative[1][U\[Theta]][r] + 2*r*(-1 + v)*Derivative[2][Ur][r]), 8*(-1 + v)*Ur[r] + 12*(-1 + v)*U\[Phi][r] + r*(-2*Derivative[1][Ur][r] + (-1 + 2*v)*(2*Derivative[1][U\[Theta]][r] + r*Derivative[2][U\[Theta]][r])) == 0, U\[Theta][r] + U\[Phi][r] == 0}, {Ur, U\[Theta], U\[Phi]}, r]
```

but Mathematica did nothing and echo the same command. However, if I plug the 3rd equation into the first two equations, Mathematica can solve the problem like the following:

```
DSolve[{4*(-5 + 8*v)*Ur[r] - 6*(-3 + 4*v)*U\[Theta][r] == 2*r*(4*(-1 + v)*Derivative[1][Ur][r] + 3*Derivative[1][U\[Theta]][r] + 2*r*(-1 + v)*Derivative[2][Ur][r]), 8*(-1 + v)*Ur[r] - 12*(-1 + v)*U\[Theta][r] + r*(-2*Derivative[1][Ur][r] + (-1 + 2*v)*(2*Derivative[1][U\[Theta]][r] + r*Derivative[2][U\[Theta]][r])) == 0}, {Ur[r], U\[Theta][r]}, r]
```

Could anyone explain why the first try fails please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: These are "ordinary" and not "partial", correct? In your first example your third equation isn't a differential equation and DSolve solves systems of differential equations.. Sometimes MMA is able to recognize such things as "differential-algebraic" systems and solve them anyway, but people seem to regularly report problems and errors with these. In this example you can trivially solve your third equation for Uφ, eliminate the third equation and replace Uφ in the first two equations. Then MMA easily solves the system of two equations without warnings or errors. Does that explain this?

Comment: Yes, those are ODEs because they are obtained by simplifying some PDEs. Your explaination is correct. I tried differentiating the whole third equation by r deliberately and Mathematica now can solve the ODEs. Thanks again!